# Context-sensitive string splitting, preserving delimiters

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string of the form "foo-bar-1.23-4", and I need to split at the first hypen followed by a numeral, such that the result is ['foo-bar', '1.23-4']. I've tried the following:

```
>>> re.split('-\d', 'foo-bar-1.23-4', 1)
['foo-bar', '.23-4']
```

and

```
>>> re.split('-(\d)', 'foo-bar-1.23-4', 1)
['foo-bar', '1', '.23-4']
```

with suboptimal results. Is there a one-liner that will get me what I want, without having to munge the delimiter with the last element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close, try this:

```
re.split('-(?=\d)', 'foo-bar-1.23-4', 1)
```

I am using [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to accomplish this - basically I am matching a dash that is immediately followed by a numeric character.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.split('-(?=\d)', 'foo-bar-1.23-4', 1)
```

Using [lookahead](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), which is exactly what Andrew did but beat me by a minute... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Would a positive lookahead work?

```
re.split('-?=\d', 'foo-bar-1.23-4', 1)
```

Not sure if you need the ( and the ) surrounding the lookahead, but give it a shot.